# A question about the determinant of matrices with integer entries

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Motivated by some **Physics backgrounds**, let's consider the following **group** $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ which consists of matrices satisfying some conditions.

Let $M_n(\mathbb Z)$ be the **set(not a group)** of $n\times n$ matrices $A$ with integer entries and $\det A\neq 0$. Then the set $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is defined as:
$GL_n(\mathbb Z)=\left \{ A: A\in M_n(\mathbb Z),\ {A}^{-1}\in M_n(\mathbb Z) \right \}$. It's easy to verify that $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is a **group**.

Now my question is as follows: $\forall A\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$, whether $\det(A)=1$ or $-1$? I have checked that it's true for $n=1,2$ cases, but for $n\geq 3$ cases I can't prove it. Does this kind of group $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is well studied in mathematics? Or maybe this question makes no sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the adjugate formula, you can see that a matrix in $M_n(R)$, where $R$ is a commutative unital ring, is invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible in $R$. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Inverses).

Comment: @ julien , Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1=\det(AA^{-1})=\det(A)\det(A^{-1})$.  But $A,A^{-1}$ have integer entries, so have integer determinants.  Thus the determinants are either both 1 or both $-1$.

Comment: @ vadim123 Oh,I got it. From your answer, I realized that I just asked such a stupid question. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @K-boy, you're welcome.